# AWS transfer RDS mysql to another region without loosing data

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, replication, rds

I wanted to transfer my mysql databaes from us-east-1 (virginia) to eu-east-1 (ireland) without loosing any data. Also, I want to stop  virginia after transfering database from one region to other region.

I have read about read replicas. I have tried once to make one read replica to another region with public access available. Once replica was ready I have promoted it and tried to access publicly . But I was not able to access the database with same credentials .

Also, I have seen blogs related to cloud formation.

Comment: "You have tried" is not enough info. Where are the "readers" of the database data located? MLu has the point on security groups. You may think you set them properly but not really. Here is clear explanation on how to create cross region replica. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-read-replicas-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

So the question should really have title **Why I can't access *RDS Read Replica* in a different region?** Right?

My assumption is that the **Security Group** assigned to the Read Replica in *eu-east-1* didn't permit access from your location.

Or that you created the read replica in a **subnet without IGW** (Internet Gateway) and therefore its public IP wasn't accessible.

Make sure you've got the *Security Group* and *Subnet setting* correct when creating the *RDS Read Replica* and you'll be fine.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a read-replica of your existing RDS instance in another region. Then promote that read-replica to master. Now you have a separate instance running in another region. You can then stop this instance and point your applications

Refer below link

[Amazon RDS  replica user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.Create)